# Bootstrap Panels not Aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to correctly align multiple columns and rows of Bootstrap Panels.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm very new to Bootstrap and fairly new to CSS+HTML.

Here's the code for one panel;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Overall</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                 Panel Body.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Duplicate this, and we get two side by side. However, if we add an extra `</div>` at the end, the next one appears on a new line, but out of alignment. I want a similar layout to this;

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
```

Here's a screenshot of how it looks when out of alignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl5Yg.png

Thanks for any help you can give, I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: As you could see by my edit, you missed a closing div

Comment: Add `row`s and calculate the column widths appropriately for your target screen size. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/52c9ay3e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see the issue. Your markup seems fine to me. Just put your panels in a new row if you want a new row :)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Overall</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Overall</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

See this simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anup1986/4m0xfzz2/

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I hadn't realised that `<div class="row">` was for making rows. Thanks for your help :P

Comment: Hehe, maybe it was too obvious? :) Glad I could help!